# Calculating p-value for introns which are retained (or not) between 2 conditions

Tags: rna-seq, rna-splicing, molecular-genetics

I am trying to calculate p-values and ultimately FDR values for RI introns for 2 conditions of experiment I have(control and knockdown)

For every condition I have 3 biological replicates each: 3 control replicates and 3 knockdown replicates.

This is the header line of my input file.

```
chrom   Istart  Iend    strand  avg-L_R_counts-1    Sk_counts-1 avg-L_R_counts-2    Sk_counts-2
```

-1 and -2 are 2 sample conditions control and knockout respectively

avg-L_R_counts = for a particular intron, this is the average of reads 5bp up stream and downstream of the 5' end and at the 3'end of the intron

Sk_counts = This is the number of reads spanning exon-exon junction for that intron.

I have approximately 350 introns(this is yeast). I can get the Percent Spliced In values but I am interested in getting a p-value and then I can calculate the FDR values.
Can anyone point me as to what approach I should take to calculate a p-value, or what test should I use?

Comment: What is your null hypothesis? What do you want to test? That one condition has more introns than the other?

Comment: My null hypothesis is that there is no intron retention in either conditions

Answer (score 2):

Here is how we do this:

First break your gene model down into non-overlapping chunks, such that any possible gene model can be built from a combination of those chunks. E.g.

```
transcript 1 |>>>>>>>>>|----------|>>>>>>>>|---|>>>>|
transcript 2 |>>>>>>|-------------|>>>>>>>>|---|>>>>|
transcript 3 |>>>>>>|-------------|>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>|
chunks       |+++1++|+2|+++++3++++|+++4++++|+5+|+6++|
```

this can be achieved using `cgat gtf2gtf --method=genes-to-unique-chunks` from the `cgat-apps` toolkit if you don't want to code it yourself.

I call
chunks 1, 4 and 6 constitutive exon
chunk  3 constitutive intron
chunk  2 alternate intron
chunk  5 annotated retained intron.

Now use `featureCounts` to count the number of reads in each chunk.

Test the chunk counts for usage using `DEXSeq`.

Filter the results to just include chunks of type 2, 3 and 5 and recompute the FDRs.

Comment: If you have your transcripts in BED format, you can use `bedops --partition` to make chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into literature? I am not an expert in this field, but a small search on google leads me to [IRFinder](https://github.com/williamritchie/IRFinder/wiki) ([ref.](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-017-1184-4)), a tool that can assess intron retention. My advice is to see if this tool can help you, before reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the MISO algorithm for inspiration, or as a method for calculating confidence intervals of alternatively spliced isoforms: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3037023/